# Which neural networks can be used only for storing and retrieving information?

Tags: neural-networks

Is there a neural network(NN) system or architecture which can be used for only storing and retrieving information. For example; to store whole Avatar movie in HD format inside a neural network and retrieve(without loss) it from the neural network when needed. I searched the web and came across only LSTM RNN but in my understanding LSTM only stores pattern and not the content itself. If there is no such NN exist can you explain why it so?

Answer (score 6):

Neural networks are usually trained to produce a certain output given a certain input. Often the output is a classification of the input or some other form of input description. Sometimes it is an action in a game and sometimes it is indeed stored data, a memory if you will.

In that case the input is often a part of the stored data, so the NN actually completes the given input. This setup is called [autoassociative memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoassociative_memory), [Hopfield networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfield_network) are an example for this.

In your example you might give this NN the first frame of the movie Avatar and it would output the complete movie. Unfortunately this would probably be absolutely [crazy inefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfield_network#Capacity).